# How to test mailto link in Cucumber?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, mailto

I have a link like this:

> < a href= "mailto:<%= @email %>?subject=Answer to complaint&body=<%= @salutation %>,">Answer< /a>

How can I test it using Cucumber/Capybara? I mean something more than just

> And I should see "Answer"

Comment: What would be sufficient, in your opinion? That the link's href contained a mailto to the correct email?

Comment: Actually I am not really sure what should I test. I just think that  'And I should see' is not enough. What do you think?

Comment: In my opinion, testing that the href contained "mailto:#{email}" is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're concerned that the `@email` and `@salutation` values in the `mailto:` links are correct.

You can do something like this

```
page.should have_xpath("//a[contains(@href,email)]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with Cucumber step:

```
Then /^I should have a mailto link with:$/ do |table| 
  mailto_link = '//a[@href="mailto:' + table.rows_hash['recipient'] + '?subject=' + table.rows_hash['subject'] + '&body=' + table.rows_hash['body'] + ' "]'
  page.should have_xpath(mailto_link)
end
```

Comment: Your need to URL encode. ALso you should use XPATH contains() in case parameters are not in the same order

Answer (score 0):

An addition to Piotr Brudny with URL encode and contains so order of parameters won't matter (I removed the body from there, but you can probably figure it out if you need it.

```
Then(/^I should have a mailto link with:$/) do |table|
  mailto_link = ("//a[contains(@href, \"mailto:#{table.rows_hash['recipient']}\")"\
  " and contains(@href, \""+ {
    subject: table.rows_hash['subject']
  }.to_query + '")]').gsub('+', '%20')
  page.should(have_xpath(mailto_link))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer, but slightly updated example. You can put it like this:

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mailto:some_name@google.com')]")
```